# Remove a specific duplicate values and keep diagonal

Tags: r, dataframe, replace, diagonal

I have a dataset like this
[image]

I want to separate "money", "income" and "loan" on separates rows. I mean, I want to get this :

[image]

My first thought was : replicate the row and then remove extra value to get the desire result. I got this :
[image]

But I'm stuck to remove value in red. How can we do that ?

This is my code :

```
mydata = data.frame(
  name = "Vince",
  date = "16/05/1977",
  money = 20,
  city = "NY",
  income = 100,
  country = "USA",
  car = "Porsche",
  loan = 250
)

duplicated_data = do.call("rbind", replicate(3, mydata, simplify = FALSE))
```

Some help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In base R, convert to matrix and then replace non diagonal values by NAs

```r
cols = c("money", "income", "loan")
mat <- as.matrix(duplicated_data[cols])
duplicated_data[cols] <- ifelse(row(mat) == col(mat), mat, NA) #Replace with NA
```

or that could be even simpler if you're okay with having 0 instead of NAs:

```r
duplicated_data[cols] <- diag(diag(mat)) #Replace with 0
```

output

```r
   name       date money city income country     car loan
1 Vince 16/05/1977    20   NY     NA     USA Porsche   NA
2 Vince 16/05/1977    NA   NY    100     USA Porsche   NA
3 Vince 16/05/1977    NA   NY     NA     USA Porsche  250
```

Answer (score 2):

```
library(tidyverse)

pivot_longer(mydata, 
    cols = c(money, income, loan), 
    names_to = "stat") |> 
      mutate(money = ifelse(stat == "money", value, NA),
             income = ifelse(stat == "income", value, NA),
             loan = ifelse(stat == "loan", value, NA)) |> 
       select(-stat,-value)
```